# ReplaceAll and Series

Tags: replacement, series-expansion

I have:

```
Series[Cos[θ], {θ, ρ, 3}] /. θ - ρ -> x
```

Why the `ReplaceAll` does not work in this case? And how to make the replacement?

Comment: There is no expression `θ - ρ` in the `SeriesData[]` object returned by `Series[..]`  Lookup `SeriesData` and examine the output of `Series[Cos[θ], {θ, ρ, 3}] // InputForm`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
ReplacePart[
 Series[Cos[θ], {θ, ρ, 3}],
 {1 -> x, 2 -> 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

To understand why what you suggest doesn't work, look at

```
FullForm[Series[Cos[θ], {θ, ρ, 3}]]
```

This does not have any terms in `θ-ρ` to match.  You can achieve what I think you want with

```
Normal[Series[Cos[θ], {θ, ρ, 3}]] /. θ -> x + ρ // Series[#, {x, 0, 3}] &
```